# Is the location of the flute random?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

In the Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past, there is a boy in the light world who plays a flute, and his presence in the dark world asks for you to find it.

[image]

He says it can be found in the light world, in a grove where he used to play (which is the same place as where he is located in the dark world), and that he has buried it there.

I have teleported back to the light world and dug up most of this grove but still haven't found it, I remember it being somewhere around the tree stump but as you can see it's not there:

[image]

Is the location of the flute randomised or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: [here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7qgo2v3R9w) a video. Flute location is at 9:30

Comment: Nice screen shots. How are you making them?

Comment: @KatieK just using the Windows 8 snipping tool, it's also available in Windows 7 - I'm playing the game via an emulator though which makes it easier!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flute's location is not randomized. It is located in the upper left corner of that area by some flowers.

[image: bringing a whole new meaning to 'the last place you look']